# JTable not refreshing after insert using DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

**Java program with GUI controlling derby database using DefaultTableModel:**

I've a method which successfully inserts a new record to my database. When I restart the program, the new record is visible in JTable (GUI). However, I can't get the JTable to refresh and display the added record promptly.

I've read through a lot of answered questions here but nothing has worked for me so far. Any idea?

*GUI class:*

```
public class GUIClients {

ClientDatabase cDB = new ClientDatabase();
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();

JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

public JPanel createPanel() {
    cDB.createTable(tableModel);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
    panel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    ...
    return panel;
}
```

*Insert dialogue with save button:*

```
public class InsertDialog extends GUIClients {
...
saveB = new JButton("Save");
    saveB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                cl = cDB.getClient(InsertDialog.this);   
                cDB.insert(cl);

                tableModel.setRowCount(0);

                cDB.createTable(tableModel);
                table.setModel(tableModel);

                dialogPanel.dispose();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
dialogPanel.add(saveB);
...
```

*Method for creating DefaultTableModel from database data:*

```
public class ClientDatabase implements Database {

public static ResultSet rs;

public void createTable(DefaultTableModel d) {
    try {
        d.addColumn("ID");
        d.addColumn("Name");
        d.addColumn("Surname");
        d.addColumn("Mobile");
        d.addColumn("Email");
        d.addColumn("Notes");

        rs.beforeFirst();
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("ID");
            String name = rs.getString("NAME");
            String surname = rs.getString("SURNAME");
            String mobile = rs.getString("MOBILE");
            String email = rs.getString("EMAIL");
            String notes = rs.getString("NOTES");
            d.addRow(new Object[]{id, name, surname, mobile, email, notes});
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've a method which successfully inserts a new record to my database.

Then you are also responsible for adding the data to the TableModel at the same time.

You can either use the `addRow(...)` or `insertRow(..)` method of the DefaultTableModel to update the date in your TableModel and the JTable will then be updated.

Or the other approach is to redo the query and then use the `JTable.setModel(...)` method to replace the old TableModel with the new TableModel.

There is no automatic synching of database and TableModel.

Comment: Am I doing it wrong? I delete all rows in the DefaultTableModel and then recreate it like this:
    `tableModel.setRowCount(0);`
    `cDB.createTable(tableModel);`

Comment: @Gussmayer, you haven't recreated the ResultSet. I would guess the data in the ResultSet is the old data. That is that data BEFORE the insert was done. I think you need to do a new query. Also, you should not be adding columns to the TableModel. The data model already contains the appropriate number of columns. All you want to do is refresh the rows.

Comment: There is no problem in the DefaultTableModel. It's updated as soon as anything is inserted into it. Nevertheless, the JTable isn't updated.